# Decode String with HTML content in Razor MVC

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a string coming from Database as :

> <strong>Hello</strong>

Now i want my razor view to display is as:

> **Hello**

How to do this Decoding in Razor?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`HtmlHelper.Raw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568896%28v=vs.111%29.aspx). That will prevent decoding your string from the database by the view engine:

```
@Html.Raw(someString)
```

If the string is encoded in your database, then you need to call [`WebUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.htmldecode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
@Html.Raw(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(someString))
```

Comment: But i want the Razor engine to decode the string and Display Bold text on screen

Comment: @PatrickHofman is correct. If you had a string that was :
<b>My text</b> stored in a variable and you wanted to output, using the above code (@Html.Raw(...)) would output My Text in bold

Comment: Now i got the string as :
<strong&gtAt restaurant="" number="" 4<="" strong&gt="" <="" td="">
                                </strong&gtot>
And nothing is displayed on the screen.

Comment: There is a `;` missing after `gt`.

Comment: Oh Sorry..i went away for a while.
Yes..it got fixed. Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Html.Raw("<strong> Hello </strong>")`