# ASP.NET Core MVC, show string into <p> tag

Tags: c#, html, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Here is sample of my code

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class Model
{
    public string sample { get; set; }
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    Model m = new Model { 
        sample = "abc<br />def"
    }
    return View(Model);
}
```

**/View/Home/Index.cshtml**

```
@using HomeController
@model Model

<p>@Model.sample</p>
```

And, it shows in browser

`abc<br />def`

What I want is

```
abc
def
```

How I can insert **new line** into `<p>` tag using string value?

Comment: `@Html.Raw(Model.sample)`

Comment: possibly answered already at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166617/decode-string-with-html-content-in-razor-mvc

Answer (score 4):

Hi please use the following code to write HTML directly to your view :

```
@Html.Raw(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use    `\n` instead of `<br />` or you can use `@Html.Raw(Model.sample)` for it to get converted to HTML rather than a plain string.